# import custom options from another product does not work

Tags: magento2, product-import

In product one i have an option from type radio buttons.
[image]

In product two i will the same custom options like in product one.

I click on ***import options*** in Customizable Options.

The following window show me a product list to chose one:

[image]

After i select one Product and click on import, i see an empty option in product 2:
[image]

What is wrong?

How can i import custom options from product one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved in Magento 2.1.3.

But if you don't want to update, just update these files (backup them first!):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/91bd54460b3eab518ca1081bcff7074ad66a4131/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/dynamic-rows-import-custom-options.js

raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid.js

raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/91bd54460b3eab518ca1081bcff7074ad66a4131/lib/web/mage/requirejs/text.js

It worked for me (with Magento 2.1.2)